# Nativescript firebase with Angular observables

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I was trying to to get some data of my Firebase database when encountered into this problem:
Getting the data from the first path (ex.: userData/tags) all work perfect,
but when I call another function to get data from a second path (ex.: userData/tasks) nothing works, in my console there isn't any error and no listener was logged. I supposed that this was mine code error or a firebase issue, but later on i found out an interesting story.

I used this code to get the data from my database, collocate in a service class.

```
  @Injectable()
        export class Database{
        private allData: any;
        constructor(){}
            public getList(path: string): Observable<any> {
                  return new Observable((observer: any) => {
                  let onValueEvent = (snapshot: any) => {
                    this.ngZone.run(() => {
                      let results = this.handleSnapshot(snapshot.value);
                      console.dir(results);
                      observer.next(results);
                    });
                  };
                  firebase.addValueEventListener(onValueEvent, `/${path}`).then((msg)=>{console.dir(msg)}).catch((error)=>{console.error(error);});
                }).share();
              }

        private handleSnapshot(data: any) {
        //empty array, then refill and filter
        this.allData = [];
        if (data) {
          for (let key in data) {
            let result = (<any>Object).assign({ key: key }, data[key]);
            this.allData.push(result);
          }
        }
        return this.allData;
      }
        }
```

Calling my code from a component page called A with UI interface, all works right.
I created a new component called B, only backend code without UI for the moment: nothing work, as I said before.

When I add the UI part suddently all works properly!!!

Component page code of A & B:
page.ts (A & B)

```
export class Page{
    public data$;
    constructor(db: Database){
      this.data$ = this.db.getList();
    }
  }
```

page.html (Only A)

```
 <ListView [items]="data$ | async">
    <ng-template let-item="item">
        <StackLayout>
        <Label [text]='item.title'></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

By the way it also happens when querying the database.

I can't say if this is related to Nativescript, Firebase, Angular or just an error with my architecture. The worst things is that mix backend and frontend, and normally are two different developers that build this two parts.

Comment: It's really really strange: I've just found out that this is not related to the backend but only with the frontend. In the first one I display the data in the UI, in the second I've checked only with 'console.dir()'  and nothings shows out.

Comment: How did you find that out?

Comment: @PatNeedham I update the question with more details .

Comment: Why you don't use angularfire2? [link](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2)

Comment: @Rodrigo Medeiros because angularfire2 is more for web development and don't have capabilities for a native app like offline data, remote config and so on. Check the plugin of EddyVerbruggen: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase

Comment: @GiorgioPiatti For offline you can use [https://github.com/adriancarriger/angularfire2-offline](https://github.com/adriancarriger/angularfire2-offline). For remote config and so on you can use [https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase)